# Blender and three.js Exporter?

Tags: keyframes, shape-keys, three.js

I am using Blender 2.69 in Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit
and Three.js Exporter.

While exporting shapekeys and keyframe animation using three.js exporter
,the exporting works fine.But unable to animate the model.
That is using 
'mesh.morphTargetInfluences[1]=value'

not working.

am using dat.gui slider to change the value so as to control the morph  manually.

Suggest a working version of three exporter for blender
or compatible Blender or Three Exporter .

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: What exporter version do you use?

Comment: Exporter r71...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest exporting FBX or glTF ([addon](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/)) from Blender, and loading them with THREE.FBXLoader or THREE.GLTFLoader. I've tested both shapekeys and keyframe animation with GLTFLoader, and both are supported.